# How write in 2 textboxes simultaneously if one of them is within template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was looking for the answer on site but I didn't find it. I have a Windows template and within the template, I have a textbox.

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="WindowTextbox" Text="Type..." TextChanged="WindowTextbox_TextChanged" 
  FontSize="15" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
  AcceptsReturn="True" Background="#404040" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="0 0 0 23">
  </TextBox>
```

Also, I have another textbox that is created when I press the button that is dynamically created textbox.

```
void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = new Window();

        window.Show();
        window.Width = 250;
        window.Height = 250;
        window.Template = FindResource("WindowControlTemplate1") as ControlTemplate;
        
        TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
        Grid.SetRow(dynamicTextBox, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(dynamicTextBox, 0);
        this.TextPanel.Children.Add(dynamicTextBox);
       
        
    }
```

So what I want to do is that when I write something in Textbox that is within the template at the same time this text should appear in the dynamically created textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly.

Instead of this

```
TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
```

make private field

```
private TextBox _dynamicTextBox;

void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    ...

    _dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
    Grid.SetRow(dynamicTextBox, 1);
    Grid.SetColumn(dynamicTextBox, 0);
    this.TextPanel.Children.Add(_dynamicTextBox);
}
```

In your `TextChanged` event of `WindowTextbox` set the text to your `_dynamicTextBox`.

```
private void WindowTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if(sender is TextBox txt)
   {
      _dynamicTextBox.Text = txt.Text;
   }
}
```